# igx grid inline feature doesn't work well with custom columns

Tags: angular, igx-grid

I working on inline edit using ignite-ui-angular grid and it highlights all rows when I select a row and also save/cancel prompt panel appears in wrong row[image].  Their example works but I am customizing column so I think that maybe the problem but not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [Grid Row Editing topic](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/grid/row-editing), 'primaryKey' is required for row editing operations.

```html
<igx-grid 
  [data]="data" 
  [primaryKey]="'ProductID'" 
  width="100%" 
  height="500px" 
  [rowEditable]="true"
  ></igx-grid>
```

Having in mind that, I assume that in your scenario ‘primaryKey’ is set to a column that is not existing in the underlying data source of the [igxGridComponent](https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/docs/typescript/latest/classes/igxgridcomponent.html).

Please verify that the primary key is set correctly.

Comment: thanks Martin, I had the wrong primary key value.  once I restarted the site, it seems to work now